# serialize a datetime as an integer timestamp

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I would like for django rest to not convert my DateTime model field into a string date represtation when serializing it.

```
response_date = serializers.DateTimeField(source="updated_at")
```

I would like this to come out as

> 1411880508

and not

> "2014-09-28T05:01:48.123"

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You'll want to write a [custom serializer field](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields#custom-fields), like so:

```
class TimestampField(serializers.Field):
    def to_native(self, value):
        epoch = datetime.datetime(1970,1,1)
        return int((value - epoch).total_seconds())
```

To support write operations you'd want to inherit from `WritableField` and also implement `from_native()`.

**EDIT for DRF 3.x & Python 3.8:**

```
class TimestampField(serializers.Field):
    def to_representation(self, value):
        return value.timestamp()
```

If you want a JavaScript style timestamp:

```
class JsTimestampField(serializers.Field):
    def to_representation(self, value):
        return round(value.timestamp()*1000)
```

Comment: AFAIK the datetime is stored in the database as a number. I was hoping to get that number as instead of having to iterate over all records in the queryset. I fear there will be performance implications for both this and my own approach.

Comment: In case you come by this answer and are using DRF 3.x, the `to_native` method is now `to_representation`

Answer (score 25):

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # if you want with milliseconds or
    'DATETIME_FORMAT': '%s.%f', 
    # only with seconds
    'DATETIME_FORMAT': '%s', 
}
```

Result in REST will be **string**

1. "1517863184.666435"
2. "1517863249"

If you want **float(or integer) value in API**, than you can **use monkey patching**.

Put the file `monkey_patching.py` in any of your `apps` and import it in app's `__init__.py` file. ie:

**app/monkey_patching.py**

```
#app/monkey_patching.py
import six
from rest_framework import ISO_8601
from rest_framework.fields import DateTimeField
from rest_framework.settings import api_settings


def to_representation_ext(self, value):
    if not value:
        return None

    output_format = getattr(self, 'format', api_settings.DATETIME_FORMAT)

    if output_format is None or isinstance(value, six.string_types):
        return value

    if output_format.lower() == ISO_8601:
        value = self.enforce_timezone(value)
        value = value.isoformat()
        if value.endswith('+00:00'):
            value = value[:-6] + 'Z'
        return value
    
    # FOR INTEGER RESULT 'DATETIME_FORMAT': '%s',
    # return int(value.strftime(output_format))

    # FOR FLOAT RESULT 'DATETIME_FORMAT': '%s.%f',
    return float(value.strftime(output_format))


DateTimeField.to_representation = to_representation_ext
```

**app/**init**.py**

```
#app/__init__.py
import app.monkey_patching
```

Tested with Django version 2.0.10 and Python 3.5.9

Comment: This answer is great! Further more, can it be formated to a float?

Comment: I don't believe so, also this is causing some issues for me with FilterSet parameters

Comment: but it is not int

Comment: @MohammadTorkashvand added info for int and float results

Comment: @YanQiDong added info for int and float results

Answer (score 15):

I was not able to get Tom's example to work and it seemed the values were not being modified. However it gave me a starting point and after some reading I found a way to produce the desired result:

**[METHOD 1]**

*serializers.py*

```
import time

class TimestampField(serializers.Field):
    def to_representation(self, value):
        return int(time.mktime(value.timetuple()))

class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ts = TimestampField(source="my_fieldname") #Source must be a models.DateTimeField

    class Meta:
        model = myModel
        fields = ('id', 'ts')
```

JSON output:

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "ts": 1475894303
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "ts": 1475833070 
}]
```

**[METHOD 2]**

Tom's explanation and the previous mentioned method are definitely more on track with maintaining standards (as the results are actually of type integer).

However a quick and dirty solution is to specify the [format parameter for the DateTimeField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#datetimefield) and set it to show the value in seconds.

**Note this probably won't work correctly on Windows machines!**
And may result in a *ValueError: Invalid format string*

To try it out just include the "format" keyword parameter in your serializer field like so:

*serializers.py*

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):    
    timestamp = serializers.DateTimeField(format="%s")

    class Meta:
        model = myModel
        fields = ('id', 'ts')
```

JSON output:

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "ts": "1475890361"
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "ts": "1475833070"
}]
```

Additionally you may include microseconds:

```
timestamp = serializers.DateTimeField(format="%s.%f")
```

If you want to test the functionality in your own interpreter (to verify your OS supports the %s parameter) just copy over these lines:

```
import datetime
print datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%s') #datetime formatted as seconds for REST

import time  #This is just for confirmation
print time.mktime(datetime.datetime.now().timetuple()) #time object result as float
```

I feel this method is a little inconsistent with the OPs question because the result is not actually of type integer, instead it is a string representation of an integer/float - and REST will surly add quotes around the value.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. format="%s" is much cleaner!

Comment: Side note for method 2, you can set the global default format in your `settings.py` like so `REST_FRAMEWORK = { 'DATETIME_FORMAT': '%s.%f'}`

Answer (score 4):

Although I prefer the answer given by Tom Christie as it is more robust.
I decided to post my solution for the benefit of the potential readers

```
response_date = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_timestamp')
def get_timestamp(self, obj):
    #times 1000 for javascript.
    return time.mktime(obj.updated_at.timetuple()) * 1000
```

Answer (score 4):

Global Configuration:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DATETIME_FORMAT': '%s.%f',
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In python, the timestamp is 10 digit. However, in Javascript, it is 13 digit.

Therefore, if you want to return Javascript format timestamp in global configure, just add '000' after '%s':

```
JS_TIMESTAMP = '%s000'

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DATETIME_FORMAT': JS_TIMESTAMP,
    'DATE_FORMAT': JS_TIMESTAMP
}
```

The result will looks like this: 1567413479000

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned before you can set timestamp format for all datetimes globally by:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DATETIME_FORMAT': '%s',
}
```

But this doesnt work for regular dates, to make it work for dates you also have to set:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DATE_FORMAT': '%s',
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@megajoe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3173323/megajoe) for [monkey patch solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26083583/serialize-a-datetime-as-an-integer-timestamp/48658795#48658795). I was developing on windows so was getting invalid format string since windows does not support any "%s" format (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fe06s4ak.aspx).

So I used monkey patch like [@megajoe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3173323/megajoe) and tweaked the solution a little to return `value.timestamp()` for "%s.%f" and `int(value.timestamp())` for "%s".